# How to make a connection between 2 tables?

Tags: php, database, laravel

I need to get `profile_picture` from table `users`, based on `user_id` from table `log`, but everything what I used was wrong.Can you help me with this code?

Here is my model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Log extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'logs';


    public $timestamps = false;

    use SoftDeletes;
    // protected $softDelete = true;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id','log','date','type','article_type', 'formatted_date','link','action_user_id','action_name','action_username','item_id'
    ];


    public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
}
```

Here is my view

```
@foreach($users as $user)

<img style="margin-right: 10px" src="{{ asset('thumbnail') }}/{{ $user->profile_picture }}" alt="">
@endforeach
```

Here is my controller

```
public function myAlerts($page = null)
{
$users =  \App\Log::with('users')
            ->where('user_id', '=', 'profile_picture')
            ->get();
}
```

But I got this error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::users()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made **user** method in model and you're calling **users**

```
public function myAlerts($page = null){
    $users =  \App\Log::with('user')->get();
}
```

If you want to check $user id then you can check like

```
public function myAlerts($page = null){
    $userid = 5;

    $users =  \App\Log::with('user')->wherehas(['user'=>function($q) use($userid) {
        $q->where('id',$userid);
    }])->get();
}
```

Comment: Hey. At `dd($users)` I got `Collection {#794 ▼
  #items: []
}`

Comment: Make sure in your logs table have data or logs table is connected with the user. otherwise now the relationship is calling perfectly.

Comment: How can I check if logs table is connected with the user?

Comment: Like, Check-in logs table user_id is foreign key and all user_id is existed or not. or one thing which I don't understand why you compare `user_id` with `profile_picture`?

Comment: I edited my answer and try like this you'll get all logs with user.

Comment: Here is my Logs table: https://imgur.com/a/Lg6VMqg , I need to get profile_picture based on user_id of the user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200298/discussion-between-laravel-and-andrew).